# Appearance of Work Sans font is different on Adobe XD and Web via CSS

Tags: html, css, fonts, zurb-foundation, adobe-xd

So I've been designing a website on Adobe XD and then developing it using HTML/CSS. I've been using the foundation framework for front-end.

I used the font "Work Sans" and have tried to keep everything between CSS and XD identical. My CSS includes the same font-family, font-size, line-spacing, font-weight, color and alignment. However, it still appears differently when implemented.

Below are screenshots of the element in AdobeXD and CSS.

**Adobe XD**

[image]

**CSS**

[image]

As you can see, the font appears to be thinner in the CSS version.\

Here's a screen grab of XD font settings

[image]

Here's my CSS (font family is specified in a separate class, however, it shows as the computed value when I inspect the element).

```
.about_parameter_head {
    color:#1F91DC;
    font-size:3.25rem;
    margin-bottom:0.125rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I suspect it's something to do with "bold roman" vs "bold"? However, CSS won't accept "bold roman" as a valid entry.

So far, I've tried setting font weight to "bolder" and "800" but it stays the same

I've check all over, and really can't figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: `bold roman` is not a valid font weight, however you could try `bolder`. Available font weights are `100 - 900`, `lighter`, `light`, `normal`, `bold`, `bolder`

Comment: You have to validate in the font file what bold roman is set too. check the font-face declaration. And BTW i can't find Bold Roman in the Google version of the font : https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Work+Sans

Comment: @Beauceron I've actually been confused for the same reason. I've used the google version  for both AdobeXD, as well as on the web. No idea where "Bold Roman" comes from. However, I included a few of the styles from Google fonts and updated my font reference tag. Was able to resolve the issue with font weight 600. Thanks for all the assistance.

Comment: Check below links, helped me a little, but in my case I need to do some manual alteration to get the web closer to the xd Design

https://www.reddit.com/r/Adobe_XD/comments/naqo9m/anyone_notice_fonts_always_look_lighter_in_xd/

https://community.adobe.com/t5/adobe-xd-discussions/font-weights-appearing-heavier-in-browser-chrome-and-safari-then-in-xd/td-p/11293936